# Create R function(s) that mimic this git repo for combining DTW and Granger Causality test

Tags: r, matlab

I have read a research paper titled "Variable-lag Granger Causality for Time Series Analysis" and have been attempting to convert the functions for their proposed methodology from Matlab to R. I frankly have next to no experience in Matlab and am struggling to do so. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Here is the repo. https://github.com/CompBioUIC/DTWGrangerFramework

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found something that is at minimum similar that has already been built in R.

See here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VLTimeCausality/VLTimeCausality.pdf